# Cannot convert character to integer in c++ in loop

Tags: c++, integer, character

Why my code shows nothing for the input of 10 5 3. It is work for everything till 1 to 9 but whenever it goes for 10 or greater then 10 then doesn't show any output. I also try to use atoi() for it but error in this line int x = str[j] - '0' . Please help me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, sum = 1, num = 0;
    string str;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        getline(cin, str);
        for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            if(str[j] != ' ') {
                int x = str[j] - '0'; // Here is the problem even I use atoi() but error
                sum *= x;
                num = sum;
            }
        }
        if(num != 0) {
            cout << num << endl;
            num = 0;
            sum = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When `x` is 0, what does `sum *= x` do?

Comment: You're multiplying all the digits. When you multiply by 0, you get 0.

Comment: what to do instead to convert character to integer in this case

Comment: You're converting it to an integer correctly. The problem is with what you're doing with the integer after you convert it.

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be for `10 5 3`? You're multiplying the digits, so `1*0*5*3 = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your post why you have two variable `num` and `sum`. It seems redundant.

Assuming you just need `num`, replace the lines

```
sum *= x;
num = sum;
```

by

```
num = (10*num + x);
```

to get the numbers right.

Also, when you encounter a space, you'll need to reset `num` to `0`. Otherwise, the input `10 8` will be treated as `108`.

```
for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
    if(str[j] != ' ') {
        num = (10*num + x);
    } else {
       // Use num and then reset it 0
       // ...
       num = 0;
    }
}
```